# One for All Trophy

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-3

Which characters count as "additional" towards the [One for All Trophy](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/Assassins-Creed-III/One-for-All) trophy?

> With any of the additional characters, perform 20 ‘Revive’ actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the three characters provided in The Battle Hardened Pack DLC (which is the DLC which adds the trophy) count towards this trophy: **The Governor**, **The Highlander**, and **The Wild Coyote Man**. Since they aren't labeled when selecting characters, here's an image of them:

[image: 3 New Multiplayer Characters]

The only mode out there that lets you choose one of them every time is Wolfpack mode. Playing in Manhunt or other team modes requires the team leader to select one of these three characters, which can get a bit frustrating. If you play Wolfpack with other players, you can always just let a teammate go attack a target and likely there will be others there that will stun him and run off, then you can swoop in for the revive.

Answer (score 0):

These "additional characters" are part of an unreleased DLC. There are other trophies for the unreleased DLC as well. These trophies do not count towards the platinum trophy; do not worry.

Comment: However, they do count against the precentage in the trophy showroom, so even if you get the platinum trophy, you won't get 100 % completion before buying the coming DLC and getting these trophies.

Comment: @KeFor82 Do you have a source for this?  DLC shouldn't be required for achievements.

Comment: @fbueckert DLC is required for DLC trophies, which is what this is. You can still get the platinum without the DLC, but you can't get 100%.

Comment: When does the unreleased DLC be released?

Comment: Early as possible next year, or "when it's ready." Of course, it's likely that it's mostly ready, but they want to release it in parts to make money. You can buy the season pass to get it cheaper.

Comment: Yes, you will still get 100% on "Assassin's Creed III" (subcategory) in "Assassin's Creed III," (overall game) but not 100% in "Assassin's Creed III." (overall game)